# How to preserve text formatting when replacing selected text in Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-addins, word-addins

I want to make a Word add-in which will transform selected text from Latin to Cyrillic, vice versa. I made an algorithm, but with a temporary string, which is returned to Word selection object. But I lose text formatting in that selection (if there is more than one text font, style, format, etc. then the whole new text will be the same format as the first format that appears in the selection).

Is there any way to copy or save (or whatever) the format of each character in the selection?

Comment: Strings, as such, have no formatting.

Comment: @macropod of course they don't. But Word text definitely has, that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: Post your code so ppl can see what you're doing.